# How to change boolean field value based on boolean field in other form odoo?

Tags: odoo

I'm having one boolean field in mrp form and other boolean field in stock picking form.
i need to set mrp_boolean to true if stock_boolean set to true.

Kindly help me here|

Comment: partial information you share, which odoo versions you check. You can find the link between stock and mrp(in odoo there have) so you have to make the compute function based on stock_boolean so whenever this field changes the compute trigger, you can set the same value in mrp.

Comment: Thanks @Dipen, I'm using version 14 for this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **related field** concept, Try this.

Example:

```
mrp_boolean = fields.Boolean(related="picking_id.stock_boolean", store=True)
stock_boolean = fields.Boolean("Stock Boolean")
```